# To remove the hyperlink from the date

Tags: list, date, hyperlink, format, fetch

I am trying to create a Google Apps script to do the conversion of the following list:

2024-01-10 - Magic Firewall Ruleset Update Issues https://stspg.io/862d2lcjvc40

2024-01-10 - Issues with Zero Trust Egress Policies https://stspg.io/kl2cscd8nxbl

to:

Jan 10 - [Magic Firewall Ruleset Update Issues](https://stspg.io/862d2lcjvc40)

The result from the script is almost there, but it also hyperlink the date which I want to avoid.

[Jan 10 - Magic Firewall Ruleset Update Issues](https://stspg.io/862d2lcjvc40)

Here is the script, any ideas or pointers on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Convert and Hyperlink', 'convertAndHyperlink')
      .addToUi();
}

function convertAndHyperlink() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

  if (!selection) {
    showMessage('Please select text to convert.');
    return;
  }

  var elements = body.getParagraphs();

  if (elements.length === 0) {
    showMessage('No text found in the document.');
    return;
  }

  elements.forEach(function (paragraph) {
    var text = paragraph.getText();
    var convertedLine = convertLine(text);

    // Clear existing paragraph content
    paragraph.clear();

    // Create a new text element with the converted line
    var newText = paragraph.appendText(convertedLine);

    // Set the hyperlink on the title
    newText.setLinkUrl(getUrlFromText(text));
  });
}

 function convertLine(line) {
  // Example line: "2024-01-10 - Magic Firewall Ruleset Update Issues https://stspg.io/862d2lcjvc40"
  var parts = line.split(' ');
  var date = parts[0];
  var title = parts.slice(1, -1).join(' ');  // Exclude the last two elements
  var url = parts[parts.length - 2];

  // Check if the date is valid
  var formattedDate = (new Date(date) !== 'Invalid Date') ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), 'GMT', 'MMM dd') : '';

  // Create formatted line without the second hyphen
  var formattedLine = formattedDate + (formattedDate !== '' ? ' ' : '') + title;

  return formattedLine;
}


function showMessage(message) {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Message', message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}

function getUrlFromText(text) {
  var regex = /https:\/\/[^\s]+/;
  var match = text.match(regex);
  return match ? match[0] : '';
}
```

Thank you.

Tried so many stuff.